# Difference between G_create and G_txcreate

Tags: gas

I am reading the yellow paper https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf

There is a gas cost for account creation: G_create.

And there is a gas cost for account creation after Homestead fork: G_txcreate.

They are both 32000 gas.

The text appears to refer to them interchangeably. In the main text it refers to G_txcreate. But in the gas usage table it refers to G_create.

Did I miss something? And what is the actual amount of gas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`G_txcreate` is used to define the intrinsic gas - the amount
of gas a transaction requires to be paid prior to execution.

`G_create` is gas paid for `CREATE` opcode.

---

E.g. if the transaction `to` address is `0x0` then at least `(G_transaction + G_txcreate + ...)` gas limit has to be set, otherwise the transaction will be considered invalid (the node won't even try executing it).

When the transaction is executed `G_create` will be subtracted from the remaining gas.

`G_create` is also used for contract-creating message calls. E.g. when you send a transaction to call some function of a contract and as part of this function a new contract is created, `G_create` will be subtracted from current gas. `G_txcreate` is irrelevant here because the transaction is not contract-creating.

It makes sense that `G_txcreate` is equal to `G_create` because if it's known in advance that a new contract will be created in the transaction then it's cost has to be paid upfront.